# How to set basic auth, content-type and data to send in axios post request?

Tags: javascript, react-native, http, axios

I'm a beginner with React Native and I'm trying to send data to IBM speech to text conversion Api with axios. I'm getting the response in Postman but I can't set my data in axios request. The request needed basic auth, content-type and file (data). How to set all of this in axios request?
I'm getting a status code of 415 [This is the code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMXWo.png).

```js
axios
      .post(
        IBMURL,
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3',
          },
        },
        {
          auth: {
            username: 'apikey',
            password: ApiPassword,
          },
        },
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Reponse', response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

`axios.post` requires a body after the `url`:

```js
axios.post(url, body, options);
```

Passing `null` or and empty object should solve it.

Comment: I did try to add an object at the second parameter place but it didn't work. Please see the above example code I'm already having 3 parameter pass to an object

Comment: You have it wrong, the `options` argument with your header should be the last